# Is there a single word meaning "a repulsive or loathsome person"?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

**Does the English language have any words in present use that would be synonymous with the figurative sense of the now obsolete *mesel*, 'a repulsive or loathsome person'?**

I am well aware of the **tons** of hyponyms (subcategories) of this idea—*jerks* (repulsively rude people), *assholes* (repulsively aggressive people), *monsters* (repulsively violent people), *psychos* (repulsively dangerous people), *sluts* (still typically repulsively sexual people despite occassional attempts to find sex less repulsive), *letches* (repulsively sexually focused people), &c. &c. &c.—but is there anything left that just covers the entire general idea of someone you just instinctively shrink back from?

The original literal sense of *mesel* was *leper*, so the figurative sense captured the sense of revulsion at the sight of a person falling apart before your eyes. Present-day *leper*, though, is more focused on the social shunning that came with that, rather than the revulsion itself. *Undesirables* comes close but not quite there.

**Do we not have a single word for this any more? or what am I forgetting?** If there isn't one in standard English, are there dialectical or slang words that would cover this?

Comment: Well, how about miscreant?

Comment: No, there are hundreds.

Comment: @JohnLawler If you can post any that don't actually belong to the hyponyms, I'm curious.

Comment: I thought _vermin_ would fit with its figurative sense as it is an allusion to repulsive insects but it has a broader sense also used for people causing problems for the society. The slang term _grunge_ comes closer to being repulsive upon sight. _OED_ definition: "A general term of disparagement for someone or something that is repugnant or odious, unpleasant, or dull; also, dirt, grime. Also _attributive_."

Comment: I do not completely understand the ask. Does the word have to connote revulsion due to appearance?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with 'loathsome' on its own?  The definitions in the Cambridge English Dictionary suggests it covers the range. https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/loathsome

Comment: @Tuffy 'Loathsome' is wrong because it's only ever an adjective. If people started regularly calling each other 'loathsomes' and an offensive person 'a loathsome', you'd be right... but they don't.

Comment: @Ily  Why exactly would we want a word that effectively classifies people into a group, as if it gave them some sort of similarity?  Such a noun was used by Hilary Clinton to apply to a large body of supporters of the former president, Trump.  If anything, the stereotyping damaged her campaign.  Of course, that would not prevent it's getting into common use.  But would you actually want to use it?

Comment: @Tuffy Good point! "__deplorables__" as a noun is one answer for this and in the language. It is more focused on the speaker's own opinion of the people rather than anything intrinsic about them, though, which was the case with 'mesel'.

Comment: A boor comes pretty close to it. Also, troglodyte

Comment: "Bastard" is one. I don't think it's generally used to refer to something more specific than loathsomeness and repulsion.

Answer (score 0):

This is informal, but you could call such a person a **sicko.** [Cambridge defines it as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/sicko)

> someone who behaves or thinks in a strange and unpleasant, often sexual, way

In more formal speech, you could call them a **pariah.** [Cambridge defines this as:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/pariah)

> a person who is not accepted by a social group, especially because they are not liked, respected, or trusted

You could also go with the common insult **scum.** [Merriam-Webster defines it as:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scum)

> a low, vile, or worthless person or group of people

Comment: No idea why anyone is downvoting you. Sure, pariah is a comment about how others are treating you and, if anything, suggest the speaker is sympathizing, but those are the only useful suggestions so far and thanks.

Comment: @lly If so, feel free to accept the answer.

Comment: I would've if I thought they really were an exact match. Point is, they are mostly on point and certainly don't deserve any downvotes. Obviously if we get 2 and 4 years on and nothing better comes along, I will. xD